# second Jquery script is not executing from selection of a loaded php result

Tags: jquery

I have an issue trying to run 2 jquery scripts to load php files scripts.
The frist jquery script is working fine but the second jquery script does not work at all.
The first loads a php script and the second should load a second php script according to the selection resulting from the first php scxript loaded.

I have the first page (main one) named report

Included in the main page there is another one named reportVehicule
This second page includes 2 jquery scrips which are the ones below

In the page reportVehicule there is a  in which I can select a year from a list. When a year is selected it execute the first script.
The first script loads a php file with parameters and a sql query is executed to create a list of available vehicule into checkboxes
This first script is fine.

Into the newly loaded section into a  I click on a checkbox and I want the second script to run and load another php script. Actually the second script below is a test because at least I want things to work and display a simple message.Note that the second script work if I put a checkbox just after the  tag.

I do not know what to do and now need help to finsd a solution.

In short my question is: How can I have a script executed from the list of available options (checkboxes) that have been loaded from a first JQuery script into the same page?

Thank you

First JQuery script
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("select.listeDesAnnee").change(function(){

    var anneeChoisie = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    if ( anneeChoisie != "defaut")
    {
    $('#chargeAuto').load('rapJQuery.php?idUser=<?php echo $KMIdUtil ; ?>&anneeChoisie='+ anneeChoisie+ ' #listeAuto1');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#chargeAuto').load('rapJQuery.php #listeAutoVide');
    }
});
```

});

Second Jquery script(actually this is just a test because it is not working. )

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
            $("#chargeEndroit").html("Checkbox is checked.");
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $("#chargeEndroit").html("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to just the failing code snippet? The amount of information here makes it difficult to asses what is going on.

Comment: After running the first script to load some php code into the page
It  failed to execute the second script when selecting a checkbox that just load into the new section of the page.